# Can a matrix be diagonalized without changing the eigenvalues.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I'm searching the eigenvalues of a complicated matrix and I can't remember if it is alowed to diagonalize the matrix without it having an effect on the eigenvalues. I'm thinking that it is not allowed because a determinant is not invariant under row reductions but since it would make the calculations much easier I wanted to be sure and ask it.(the matrix i'm using is symmetric)

Comment: I think your definition of "diagonalize a matrix" and the typical definition of "diagonalize a matrix" aren't the same. I suspect you are asking about performing Gaussian elimination or row reduction (which does not preserve eigenvalues).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, there are many ways to start with a matrix and end up with a diagonal matrix. The method you probably have in mind is diagonalization by similarity. If you have an $n \times n$ matrix $A$ and $P$ is an invertible $n \times n$ matrix then $P^{-1}AP$and $A$ have the same eigenvalues. In particular, if $P^{-1}AP$ is diagonal, we can read off the eigenvalues. Unfortunately, such a matrix $P$ may not exist. The situation at first seems much better if $A$ is real and symmetric. In that case, such a matrix $P$ is guaranteed to exist. Even better, if $A$ is a real symmetric matrix, there exists a real matrix $P$ such that $PP^T=I, P^{-1}AP \text {is diagonal and} \det(P)=1$ , which at first glance seems wonderful, except that to find such a $P$ you usually have to find the eigenvalues first!